# Is momentum equivalent to a virtual shift in position?

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian-formalism

I have been reading a paper that offhandedly describes shifting the origin of a position term in a harmonic oscillator potential, as being equivalent to adding a momentum term in the Hamiltonian.

"This is a shift in the origin of the coordinates and, being a virtual shift in the position, produces a term in the dynamical equation for the position proportional to the rate at which the trap is being shifted."

So I am imagining the coordinate shift as,

$x \to x+\Delta x,$

but to produce the change described in the dynamical position equation, sounds like it requires this change in the Hamiltonian,

$H \to H + (\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Delta x)\, p$

I can't see how these two things are equivelent?

*A. C. Doherty, K. J. Feedback control of quantum systems using continuous state estimation. Phys. Rev. Lett. 60, (1999).*

Comment: $\uparrow$ Link?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer, I haven't read the paper.

In the paper [1] the author defines the following relationship:

$$
\dot x = \frac{p}{m}
$$

in eq (36). The author is defining an optimal control problem, whereby feedback terms are added to the Hamiltonian in both of the phase space variables $(x,p)$. It is stated that this is readily performed for $x$, but not so for $p$.

The author states that there are two possible approaches to achieve this.

In the first, the desired term in the Hamiltonian is proportional to the rate at which the position is shifted. He states this is a 'virtual shift' since it is a shift in the origin of the coordinates.

I would imagine the following transformation:

$$
x' = x + \dot x dt = x + \frac{p}{m}dt 
$$

There is now a linear momentum term in the Hamiltonian; therefore, a degree of freedom for the feedback control.

The second method is to apply a large impulse $J$ to the system:

$$
J = \int F dt = \int \frac{dp}{dt} dt = \int dp = \delta p
$$

This creates a shift in $x$ and the feedback control is through the equal and opposite impulse on the 'reset momentum'.